# python create system alias to script

Tags: python, sh

I creating an install script for my python project which installs all the external dependencies I need in order to run properly.

I want to create a system alias named `myScript` which will be alias for `path/to/script/run.py` so users could just run it by using myScript command

How can I do it?

Comment: just place it inside .bashrc?

Answer (score 5):

If your project has a `setup.py` script and you're installing your python packages, scripts, and dependencies using `setuptools` (and you should be), you can use the `entry_points` [feature](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) of `setuptools`.

setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    # other arguments here...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'myScript = my_package.run:main',
        ],
    },
)
```

Your project structure should look like this:

```
setup.py
/my_package
    __init__.py
    run.py
```

Your `run.py` script should have a `main()` function, which will get run when someone types `myScript` at the command line.  This works regardless of what shell they use or what platform you're on.

Answer (score 0):

In terminal:

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

then inside .bashrc:

```
alias myScript ='python path/to/script/run.py'
```

reload bash, and it should work

To be sure where you are executing your script, to now which file to edit, you can check this with Python:

```
>>> import platform
>>> platform.system()
'Linux'
>>>
```

To check if it is Mac:

```
platform.mac_ver()
```

Comment: is there a way for me to know if the systems uses .bachrc (linux, ubuntu etc..) or .profile (Mac)

Comment: @AsafNevo I which way? even before you create alias? Or inside python script?

Comment: I want to make sure i'm adding the alias to right file.. so it should be from inside the python script

Comment: It depends, I'm a [Fish Shell](http://www.fishshell.com) user, also someone may use `zsh`, etc.